# Feature request: Suggest linked questions when flagging a question as a duplicate

Tags: feature-request

I was looking at this question:

[Can I generate comments using roxygen2 without building an R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27948768/can-i-generate-comments-using-roxygen2-without-building-an-r-package)

I realised that the answer was actually in a linked question:

[Possible to create Rd help files for objects not in a package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923405/possible-to-create-rd-help-files-for-objects-not-in-a-package?lq=1)

I then moved to flag the original question as a duplicate. To my surprise, the linked question is not one of the suggested questions.